# 0x TransformERC20 WalletExecuteDelegateCallFailedError

Tags: 0x

During simple swap with transformERC20, sometime the transaction revert with IncompleteFillSellQuoteError and WalletExecuteDelegateCallFailedError. I saw on stackexchange that this issue is caused by 0x Inconsistent calculation of slippage, and have to be resolved 2022 ago. But it isn't on BSC or Polygon. Some idea or specifics parameters to get for swap/v1/quote work fine ? the symptom is that soldAmount is smaller as sellAmount so the transaction revert ! Thank by advance